# Can I sync two bazel-remote-cache's using rsync

Tags: build, bazel

I have a build pipeline that builds and tests changes before they are merged to the main line.  Once that happens, it would be great if the Bazel actions from that build are available to developers.  Unfortunately, the build pipeline runs in the cloud and uses an in-cloud cache, but the developers use an on-premises cache.

I am using https://github.com/buchgr/bazel-remote

Does anyone know if I can just `rsync` the artifacts from the data directory of the cloud cache to the developers' cache in order to give them access to the pre-built artifacts?  Normally, I would just try it out, but I'm concerned about subtle issues that might poison the cache or negatively effect the hit rate, so I'm hoping to hear from someone who understands the code before I go digging.

Comment: we're facing the exact same predicament. I'll reply to this thread when we find a viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rsync the cache directory contents and use them from another location, but this won't work with a running bazel-remote- the items will be ignored until bazel-remote is restarted.

Another option would be to use the http_proxy configuration file setting to automatically put/get cache items to/from another bazel-remote instance. An example configuration file was recently added to README.md in the bazel-remote git repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I will explore using a HA proxy in front of a running instance and a dead instance.  That way, I can do the rsync, spin up the dead instance and tear down the old one.  My only concern is what Bazel will do if a HTTP transfer of a build action fails because the old instance dies in the middle of it. Do you know how Bazel will behave if a cache HTTP request fails due to a broken HTTP connection?

Comment: Or, alternatively, just leave two instances running behind the HA proxy and restart them one at a time. Same issues either way

Comment: Or write a small script to walk a bazel-remote cache dir, sort the items by mtime, and upload them to a second bazel-remote instance over HTTP?

Comment: IIRC bazel should fall back to building locally if there's a connection error. I don't think running two instances of bazel-remote behind HA proxy will work if you want to use bazel's "build-without-the-bytes" feature.